# How to fix the DataTables not working after publish in IIS using MVC

Tags: javascript, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with my MVC App with datatables it not working after I publish it into IIS but when I run my source code it works

When I try to troubleshoot I found out something:

[image]

Here is my controller code for datatables:

```
     public ActionResult LoadData()
    {
                var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
                var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
                var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
                var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
                var searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();

                //Paging Size (10,20,50,100)    
                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                int recordsTotal = 0;

                 var customerData = (from tempcustomer in objCmp.ToList()                               
                                select tempcustomer);
                
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
                {
                    customerData = customerData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
                }
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
                {
                    customerData = customerData.Where(m => m.FileAs.Contains(searchValue.ToUpper()) || m.ContactID.Contains(searchValue.ToUpper()) || m.Gender.Contains(searchValue.ToUpper()));
                 }

                recordsTotal = customerData.Count();
                var data = customerData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
    }
```

Hopefully you cant help me.

Comment: If you're using JSON response, you'll need to set mime type `application/json` in IIS.

Comment: application/json the entry type is Inherited is that what you mean? but still is not working

Comment: Ok, make sure you are calling the correct route.